# Overloading :+= in Ruby

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading

I want to define a custom :+= method on my Ruby class that modifies the instance. However, the following code raises `syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ';' or '\n'`

```
def +=(other)
  @value += other.to_f
end
```

What are my options here? I see that `Fixnum` has `:+@` and `:-@` methods, but I don't exactly see what they do in the documentation. Are those the methods I want to write?

Comment: defining `:+@` actually redefines the entire object to be a Float, rather than update the instance variable, as I intended.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353913/ruby-overloading), which has a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike C++ or other languages with robust overrides, there's no such method as `+=` in Ruby.

What's happening internally is a sort of expansion. For example:

```
x += n
```

If `x` is a variable, then this is equivalent to:

```
x = x.send(:+, n)
```

If `x=` is defined, then this is equivalent to:

```
send(:x=, x.send(:+, n))
```

Whatever you need to do to override must be to redefine `x=` or `+` on the class of `x`.

Remember that the `+` method should **not** modify `x`. It's supposed to return a copy of `x` with the modification applied. It should also return an object of the same class of `x` for consistency.

Your method should look like:

```
def +(other)
  # Create a new object that's identical in class, passing in any arguments
  # to the constructor to facilitate this.
  result = self.class.new(...)

  result.value += other.to+f

  result
end
```

Comment: Gotcha (on the last part). That's what I have for the base `:+` method. I want to be able to perform all 4 basic arithmetic operations, and their destructive forms on this object. I'm confused how to implement that internal expansion, if that makes any sense

Comment: `Remember that the + method should not modify x. It's supposed to return a copy of x with the modification applied.` I agree with this, but I wonder if you have any kind of reference?

Comment: Whatever you've got to do to return a *copy* of the object with the modification applied, you do that. @emaillenin has an answer below with another type of example.

Comment: @tadman Got it! I just had to write up both forms of the method and inspect the process step by step to understand. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure, but you do not need the = operator.

```
def +(other)
  @value += other.to_f
end
```

Example from [here](http://ruby.about.com/od/oo/ss/Overloading-Operators.htm):

```
class Money
  attr_accessor :value

  def +(b)
    result = dup
    result.value += b.value
    return result
  end

  def -(b)
    result = dup
    result.value += b.value
    return result
  end
end
```